# How to select and replace last two digits in a string?

Tags: regex, replace

I have large number of different numerical strings in a database, but they all starts with 111 and they are all 12 or 13 char. in length, together with beginning of 111.
In some lines they are surrounded by apostrophe, sometimes by space, (and they are not at the beginning of the line).

I tried to select last two digits with this in Notepad++

```
['111(0-9)][');]
```

but then it selects last digit and apostrophe instead of last two digits?

Comment: Please provide examples of your data along with the expected result.

Comment: `[]` defines a character class. "any of the characters inside the `[]` can match a SINGLE character in the input. since you have `'`, `1`, `(`, `)` and  range `0-9` (making the `111` totally redundant) you allow a quote, or a digit, or one of the brackets, followed by a quote, bracket, OR semicolon.

Comment: Try using `\d{2}(?=\D*$)` to select the last 2 digits in a string that are consecutive.

Comment: Add `Notepad++` tag if that's what you're using.

Comment: This is very unclear without an [MCVE (minimal complete verifiable example)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). To match last two digits at the end of the line, use `\d{2}$`. Last two digits at the end of the document: `\d{2}\z`.

Answer (score 0):

A 12 or 13 digit matching, general purpose regex would be either of these:

`(?<!\d)111\d{7,8}(\d{2})(?!\d)`

Explained

```
 (?<! \d )     # Not a digit behind
 111           # '111'
 \d{7,8}       # 7 or 8 digits
 ( \d{2} )     # (1), Last 2 digits (to be replaced)
 (?! \d )      # Not a digit ahead
```

The quicker version

`111(?<!\d111)\d{7,8}(\d{2})(?!\d)`

Explained

```
 111                 # '111'
 (?<! \d 111 )       # Not a digit before '111'
 \d{7,8}             # 7 or 8 digits
 ( \d{2} )           # (1), Last 2 digits (to be replaced)
 (?! \d )            # Not a digit ahead
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
\b(111\d{7,8})(\d\d)\b
```

This matches the last two digits of your target numbers as group 2.
The first part is in group 1 (if you need to put it back intact in a replacement).

I've used `\b` - word boundary - to match either end.